# Obtener un único valor desde un left join en un rango <=

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

Necesito obtener el valor más alto en una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT CASO.IDCASO,
   CASO.FECHACREACION,
   GTALT.IDUSUARIO,
   GTALT.FECHACREACION
    FROM CASO 
LEFT JOIN GRUPODETRABAJO GTALT
  ON CASO.CODUSUARIOALTA = GTALT.IDUSUARIO
  AND GTALT.FECHACREACION <= CASO.FECHACREACION
```

Este es el tema, necesito quedarme con un único registro, el mayor que cumpla la condición <= de la FECHACREACION.

Comment: fechacreacion es unico? o puede haber mas de un registro con misma fechacreacion?

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro

Esta es una forma de obtener el primer registro del conjunto en Oracle (No es la única), la clave es ordenarlo por el campo que requieres (fecha en tu caso) y luego anidar el conjunto dentro de otro y con ROWNUM obtener un único registro (si quisieras más registros ROWNUM <= N).

```
SELECT * FROM MITABLA
WHERE ROWNUM=1
ORDER BY MICAMPO
```

En tu caso particular sería:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CASO.IDCASO,
    CASO.FECHACREACION,
    GTALT.IDUSUARIO,
    GTALT.FECHACREACION
    FROM CASO 
    LEFT JOIN GRUPODETRABAJO GTALT
        ON CASO.CODUSUARIOALTA = GTALT.IDUSUARIO
        AND GTALT.FECHACREACION <= CASO.FECHACREACION
    ORDER BY GTALT.FECHACREACION DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Christian, me sirvió tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: De nada Alejandro, marca la respuesta como útil para que sirva de ayuda a otros.